# Выбор иконки для ярлыка приложения

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть проект на c#(WPF) необходимо кроме основной иконки ярлыка приложения добавить возможность выбрать еще из представленных. Понимаю, что иконку можно подгрузить отдельно из другого файла, но хотелось бы как-то осуществить из основного EXE файла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К сожалению, WPF не позволяет прикрепить несколько иконок «из коробки». Но вы можете легко загрузить иконки, указав ваш собственный res-файл.

Сам res-файл с Win32-ресуресами придётся скомпилировать вручную, один раз, при помощи rc.exe из Windows SDK.

У вас будет что-то такое в rc-файле:

```
1 ICON "mainicon.ico"
2 ICON "alternative1.ico"
3 ICON "alternative2.ico"
1 24 "app.manifest"
```

(сохраняйте файл как plain ASCII).

Откомпилировав это (`rc /r your_resource_file.rc`), вы получите res-файл, который можно подключить к проекту через свойства проекта (Application → Resources → Resource file).

---

<sub>(Данный ответ — адаптация [ответа с en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8914810/276994).)</sub>

Comment: res файл создал, при переходе (Application → Resources → Resource file) создается resx файл. При добавлении в него res файла иконки не появляются.

Comment: Дополню ответ. В свойствах проекта в "Приложение" в секции "Ресурсы" указываем RadioButton "Файл ресурсов" и выбираем созданный ранее res файл.